# Interleaving iterator methods

Tags: java, iterator

Lets say we have an Iterator:

```
Iterator i;
```

And two Java methods:

```
static X f(Iterator i)
static Y g(Iterator i)
```

They both process through an iterator and produce a result, say "sum", "product", or something else.

Let say the results of these calls for a given `i` is:

```
x == f(i)
y == g(i)
```

And lets say we have another class:

```
class Pair<X,Y>
{
  public X x;
  public Y y;
}
```

I want to write a method:

```
static Pair<X,Y> h(Iterator i)
```

So that:

```
h(i) == Pair<X,Y>(x,y);
```

How can I write `h` without modifying or rewriting `f` or `g`? The issue is that I may not be able to copy the iterator (it could be an input stream for example), so it seems like me that both `f` and `g` have to use the iterator in "parallel". I'd rather not put the entire contents of the iterator into a list, and it may not be possible, as if I'm streaming a large source I might not have enough memory. I don't require the solution have multiple threads however, and would prefer a simpler approach if possible.

Comment: Do these functions process all the elements in the iterator or do they access one element?

Comment: All the elements. Like "sum" or "product" as mentioned.

Comment: Could you define `h(Iterable)` instead?

Comment: There's no reason for tags in titles. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible to do with just the iterator you have. You'll need a quite elaborate scheme where akin to *nix's `tee` command, just for Java iterators: an object which contains your initial iterator and consumes it as needed, and can be requested to produce one or more "output" iterators. Inside you could be using a queue to store the unconsumed elements.

If you don't want multithreading, then it is simple to realize on theoretical grounds that you will absolutely have to cache the entire produce of the initial iterator. This is because both your iterator-consuming methods are based on the "pull" approach and will insist on consuming the entire sequence before returning.

BTW in Clojure the project *lamina* does something very similar, just not with Java iterators, but with a concept it calls "channels".

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to get the stacktrace to know which of the two method is calling the iterator.next method.

As long as both callers have not called next(), you block the one ahead.

- This is not optimized.
- I tried to make this code Thread safe, but as i wrote it quickly, some synchronization issue may remain. I let you review it ;)
- I let you remove the lot of System.out.println

The originalIterator is based on a List, but use the data structure you wish. As you can see, stream.iterrator() is called only once.

```
public static class InterleavingIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

    private boolean hasNext;
    private E next;

    private final Iterator<E> originalIterator;

    private final Map<String, Integer> stepCaller = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Integer>());
    private final AtomicInteger curStep = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public InterleavingIterator(Iterator<E> originalIterator, String caller1, String caller2) {
        this.originalIterator = originalIterator;
        stepCaller.put(caller1, 0);
        stepCaller.put(caller2, 0);

        hasNext = originalIterator.hasNext();
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return hasNext;
    }

    public E next() {
        String caller = getCurrentCaller();
        int currentStep = curStep.get();
        System.out.println("caller is " + caller);
        if (stepCaller.get(caller) == currentStep) {
            System.out.println("Caller " + caller + " is on current step. We need to move on.");
            // we should go on next step. But first check that all caller are done with this step.
            while (otherCallerBehind(currentStep)) {
                System.out.println("Other caller are behind. Waiting for them...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Ok, everybody is on current step. Going on.");

            synchronized (curStep) {
                if (currentStep == curStep.get()) {
                    // ok, go on.
                    curStep.incrementAndGet();
                    next = hasNext ? originalIterator.next() : null;
                    hasNext = originalIterator.hasNext();
                    System.out.println("hasNext=" + hasNext + ", next=" + next + ", currentStep=" + curStep.get());
                }
            }

        }
        E next2 = next;
        stepCaller.put(caller, stepCaller.get(caller) + 1);
        System.out.println("Caller " + caller + " is now at step " + stepCaller.get(caller) + ". Returning already fetch next : "
                + next);
        return next2;
    }

    private boolean otherCallerBehind(int currentStep) {
        for (Integer step : stepCaller.values()) {
            if (step < currentStep) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Method remove not supported");
    }

    public String getCurrentCaller() {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        //            System.out.println(stackTraceElements[3].getMethodName());
        return stackTraceElements[3].getMethodName();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> stream = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    final InterleavingIterator<Integer> interleavingIterator = new InterleavingIterator<Integer>(stream.iterator(), "f", "g");

    final AtomicInteger fres = new AtomicInteger(-1);
    final AtomicInteger gres = new AtomicInteger(-1);

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fres.set(f(interleavingIterator));
        };
    }.start();

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            gres.set(g(interleavingIterator));
        };
    }.start();

    while (fres.get() == -1 && gres.get() == -1) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(fres);
    System.out.println(gres);
}

public static Integer f(Iterator<Integer> i) {
    Integer sum = 0;
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        sum += i.next();
    }
    return sum;
}

public static Integer g(Iterator<Integer> i) {
    Integer prod = 1;
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        prod *= i.next();
    }
    return prod;
}
```

Comment: Just realized you could use a ThreadLocal variable instead of this ugly Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3].getMethodName(); to know which of f or g is calling iterator.next()

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably know what you are iterating through, you can get the values, put it into a new list, and pass it's iterator to the function.

```
Pair<X,Y> getPair(Iterator i) {
  ValObj value = null;
  List<ValObj> artList = new LinkedList<ValObj>();

  while ((value=i.next())!=null) {
    artList.add(value);
  } 

  X x = f(artList.iterator());
  Y y = g(artList.iterator());

  return new Pair<X,Y>(x,y);
}
```

Right now I noticed that you do not want to store the contents in a list. If that is the case, without any more details about the iterator, I believe it is impossible to do it.

Comment: I don't see how this works. This looks like it only uses the first element of the iterators, not potentially all of them. And I've edited the question to reflect the idea that I don't want to the entire iterator, I'd rather stream through it.

Comment: @Clinton Each call to this function will get a single Pair based on current `Iterator i` position and will advance the iterator. Next call to the function will return next elt. And so forth.

Comment: @Clinton I extended the answer. Sorry, I just noticed your note about storing the contents into a list. Can't think of anything else.